# Average working set size for a process

Tags: linux, memory, process, linux-kernel

I am running an executable in linux (c++ code). I want to calculate 'average' working set size of this executable? I have no clue in how to proceed. Can some one help me out?

Is there any command in linux to do so?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you pl try top command http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_top.htm or vmstat http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vmstat

Comment: Take a look at this page http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/proc.5.html

Comment: Thanks, How do I get the average of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inspired by Caesar:

```
pid=`ps axo 'pid,ucomm' | grep procname | awk '{print $1;}'`
while sleep 15; do grep VmRSS /proc/$pid/status || break; done > /tmp/size
awk '{ sum += $2; count++; } END { print sum/count; }' /tmp/size
```

Comment: Thanks, that solve my prob. one more doubt, Will vmsat or sar does also the same thing? Because this is referred my one friend

Comment: @mohan: vmstat gives you *system* memory information.  If you machine is doing nothing else, is in single user mode, etc, then comparing before and during could let you determine what the working set was.  But in normal operation, in general too much other stuff will be going on to draw a strong conclusion.  sar is more or less the same way.  It is system accounting, not process accounting.

Comment: The [resident set size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resident_set_size) is not the [working set size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_set_size).